# How to return common schema of partitioned parquet files with pyarrow dataset API

Tags: pyarrow, apache-arrow

I'm working with parquet files partitioned by month. I expect this code to actually return a common schema for the full data set since there are variations in columns removed/added between files.

```
dataset = ds.dataset('data/Parquet')
dataset.files
# Infer a common schema for all files in the dataset
schema = dataset.schema

# Loop over each file in the dataset and count the inferred schema columns that exist in each file schema

for file in dataset.files:
    parquet_file = pq.ParquetFile(file)
    file_schema = parquet_file.schema
    matching_cols = set(schema.names).intersection(set(file_schema.names))
    non_matching_cols = set(schema.names) - matching_cols
    print("File:", file)
    print("Total matching columns:", len(matching_cols))
    print("Total non-matching columns:", len(non_matching_cols))
    print("")
```

When I go to check that all columns exist across all individual files I'm noticing that
`ds.dataset` infers the schema as the exact copy of the first file in the partion that it reads.

```
File: data/Parquet/File1.parquet
Total matching columns: 14527
Total non-matching columns: 0

File: data/Parquet/File2.parquet
Total matching columns: 11522
Total non-matching columns: 3005

File: data/Parquet/File3.parquet
Total matching columns: 11637
Total non-matching columns: 2890
```

Am I reading the API docs incorrectly and this is the expected behaviour?

According to docs:

schema
The common schema of the full Dataset

I either expected it to return all columns across all schemas or to unify columns that exist in all schemas and drop others.

Answer (score 2):

> When I go to check that all columns exist across all individual files I'm noticing that ds.dataset infers the schema as the exact copy of the first file in the partion that it reads.

This is an [option in arrow-c++](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/apache-arrow-11.0.0/cpp/src/arrow/dataset/discovery.h#L49-L60) but unfortunately it seems it is not exposed to pyarrow.

> Am I reading the API docs incorrectly and this is the expected behaviour?
>
> According to docs:
>
> schema The common schema of the full Dataset

I would say the docs are still correct here.  In order for the datasets API to work (e.g.  reading a dataset) this schema needs to be the schema of the full dataset. The problem you are encountering is that the discovery process is not generating a valid dataset in this case.

> I expect this code to actually return a common schema for the full data set since there are variations in columns removed/added between files.

As a workaround you can use the [`unify_schemas`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.unify_schemas.html) function.  It's a little bit less convenient but otherwise should do what you want:

```
import os
import shutil

import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

shutil.rmtree("/tmp/my_dataset")
os.mkdir("/tmp/my_dataset")

one = pa.Table.from_pydict({"a": [1, 2], "b": ["x", "y"]})
two = pa.Table.from_pydict({"b": ["x", "y"], "c": [True, False]})

pq.write_table(one, "/tmp/my_dataset/one.parquet")
pq.write_table(two, "/tmp/my_dataset/two.parquet")

# Only shows 'a' and 'b' fields                                                                                                                                                                                    
print("Discovery")
print(ds.dataset("/tmp/my_dataset").schema)

schemas = []
for path in ds.dataset("/tmp/my_dataset").files:
    schemas.append(pq.read_metadata(path).schema.to_arrow_schema())

unified = pa.unify_schemas(schemas)
# Shows 'a', 'b', and 'c' fields                                                                                                                                                                                   
print("Unified")
print(unified)
```